# install some package on ubuntu 14.4 LTS shows error

Tags: 14.04

I want to install the following package on ubuntu 14.4 LTS

```
libreadline-dev   liblua5.2-dev libevent-dev  python-dev
```

But when i want to install `libreadline-dev` error shows:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libreadline-dev : Depends: libreadline6-dev (= 6.2-8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And when i want to fix it by install `libreadline6-dev` error shows :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libreadline6-dev : Depends: libreadline6 (= 6.2-8) but 6.3-4ubuntu2 is to be installed
                   Depends: libtinfo-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Also install `libevent-dev` shows error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libevent-dev : Depends: libevent-2.0-5 (= 2.0.16-stable-1ubuntu0.1) but 2.0.21-stable-1ubuntu1.14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And `python-dev` error shows:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
          Depends: python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.3) but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `apt-get install -f`. If this still gives the error of the dependencies then I guess you will have to remove and reinstall the package.